# Structuremap Using Profiles (version 2.6)

Tags: structuremap

```
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.Scan(scan =>
                {
                    scan.Assembly("CloudAssembly");  // defines profile "Cloud"
                    scan.LookForRegistries();
                });

                x.Profile("Local", cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.For<ICloudStorage>().
                        Use(() =>
                            new LocalStorage(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")));

                });
           });
```

Then I try to set it to the "Local" profile so that ICloudStorage resolves to LocalStorage.

```
        ObjectFactory.Container.SetDefaultsToProfile("Local");
        ObjectFactory.Profile = "Local";
```

Then I get this exception when activating an object that depends on ICloudStorage:

```
StructureMap Exception Code:  202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily ICloudStorage, AssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

Am I doing something wrong with the profiles?  I looked at the output of whatDoIHave and everything looks like it is configured properly.

Here's the relevant section of "whatDoIHave":

```
ICloudStorage (MyLibrary.ICloudStorage)                         Default Instance for Profile Local          Instance is created by Func<object> function:  System.Func`2[StructureMap.IContext,MyLibrary.ICloudStorage]                                                                                                                         
Scoped as:  Transient

                                                                                  Default Instance for Profile Local          Instance is created by Func<object> function:  System.Func`2[StructureMap.IContext,MyLibrary.ICloudStorage]                                                                                                                         
                                                                                  Default Instance for Profile Cloud     Configured Instance of CloudProviders.CloudStorage, CloudProviders, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply removed ObjectFactory.Container.SetDefaultsToProfile("Local") which I was calling directly after the Initialize method to use a config file instead...

```
  <StructureMap DefaultProfile="Local">

  </StructureMap>
```

And it is now working properly...